# Java Immutability behind the scenes

Tags: java, immutability

So, I'm new to Java and am trying to get my head around how immutable objects are implemented, and why they can appear to be mutable nonetheless. A lot of the sources I've looked at seem to 'suggest' what goes on under the hood, but I'd just like clarification as to whether I'm on the right track.

Using the following trivial example:

```
import java.math.*;

class BIMutability {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      BigInteger biValue = new BigInteger("2");

      for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
         System.out.println(i + ". biValue = " + biValue);
         biValue = biValue.multiply(biValue);
      }
   }
}
```

which, when run, produces:

```
1. biValue = 2
2. biValue = 4
3. biValue = 16
4. biValue = 256
5. biValue = 65536
6. biValue = 4294967296
7. biValue = 18446744073709551616
8. biValue = 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
9. biValue = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```

On the surface, it would appear that *biValue* is, in fact, mutable after all. I know that that's not the case.

My understanding is thus: *biValue* is essentially a pointer variable. Upon instantiation at runtime, heap is allocated for an object of class BigInteger, its constructor is called which (among other things) initializes the object's value according to the literal value "2", and *biValue* is finally assigned a pointer to the object space. (Is this correct?)

Subsequently, on each successive iteration of the loop, the *multiply* method allocates additional heap for a new object instantiation to contain the resulting immutable value (e.g. heap for the result of the 4th iteration is allocated and the new object assigned the value 256) and *biValue* is assigned a pointer which references the new object. (Is this also correct?)

(As an aside, from what I gather then, the previous objects' heap space are just orphaned? Or is garbage collection performed right away? If not, it just seems like you could quickly run out of heap under certain circumstances.)

So am I seeing this correctly, or am I missing important details, or...?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything you've said is correct; to clear up your confusion with garbage collection, the previous `BigInteger` object will have no more references pointing to it when `biValue` is set to something else, so it is eligible for garbage collection.  It is not garbage collected immediately, but the JVM handles that for you.

Comment: Everything you've said is correct. One thing you left unsaid is the distinction between variables and objects. `biValue` is a variable. Every variable in a  Java program either holds a primitive value (e.g., an `int` or a `double`), or else it holds an object reference. In Java (unlike C++) objects are never stored in variables. They are only ever found on the heap. `biValue` in your program is a mutable variable that holds a reference to an immutable object. If you want an immutable variable, you can either declare it to be `final`, or you can simply not write any code that assigns it.

Comment: A final variable doesn't make the object immutable. If the final is referencing a object it just means the variable cant be reassigned. A class is made immutable by making sure there are no mutating methods. There is nothing magic going on.

Comment: @jameslarge "Not write any code that assigns" does not make the variable immutable. It would be like saying that not calling any setter methods makes an object immutable. Immutability is about what you *can* do, not about what you actually do.

Comment: @Andreas, You are right. I seldom declare any public variables. A public variable is immutable if and only if it is declared to be `final`. A private variable... Well, it doesn't really matter because your code does what it does, and it won't ever do anything else unless you change it.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about how `multiply` creates a new `BigInteger` object each time you call it, and that `biValue`'s value changes in each iteration.

When we say immutability, we mean that *objects* can't be mutated, not *variables*. A variable that can't be mutated can be declared using the `final` modifier.

And yes, many immutable classes might "seem" to be mutable. In such cases, the seemingly mutating methods will create a new object.

Regarding the fate of the `BigInteger` objects in the previous iterations of the loop, yes they will be garbage collected. However, the time that this happens is non-deterministic. Note that it probably *will* fill up the heap not because GC didn't collect the unused objects, but because the number is too big.

Comment: *"Mutable objects can be mutated without reassigning to a variable"* Meh!! Unclear. You most often mutate by assigning to an *instance variable* (aka a *field*). [There are **eight** kinds of variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3): class variable, instance variable, array component, method parameter, constructor parameter, lambda parameter, exception parameter, and **local variable**.

Comment: Since you *can't* mutate an object by reassigning the variable holding a reference to that object, saying that you can mutate without reassigning is ... redundant ... and confuses the issue.

Comment: @Andreas ok, removed that line